# Material table row selection/hovering not working in angular app

Tags: javascript, java, angular, angular-material

I have a very simple project, testing material row selection/hovering. I have put it in Stack Blitz [basic-table-test](https://stackblitz.com/github/rejkid/TestBasicMaterialTable?file=README.md).
My questions are:

1. Hovering mouse over selected table row
   makes the selection to disappear.

Does anybody understand where the problems is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are defining a CSS class `.hovered` to apply a different background color when the mouse is hovering the table row.

#### Problem

Angular Material also apply a background property with a CSS selector which override your property:

```css
.mat-mdc-table tbody,
.mat-mdc-table tfoot,
.mat-mdc-table thead,
.mat-mdc-cell,
.mat-mdc-footer-cell,
.mat-mdc-header-row,
.mat-mdc-row,
.mat-mdc-footer-row,
.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-header-cell {
    background: inherit;
}
```

#### Solution

To fix this you could apply a CSS selector rule which have a higher priority than the one provided by Angular Material in the `app.component.css` file of your project example.
ex:

```css
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

/* this rule got a higher priority than the Angular Material one*/
.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-row:hover,
.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-footer-row:hover .hovered {
  background: red;
}

.highlighted {
  background: green;
}

mat-cell.mat-cell,
mat-header-cell.mat-header-cell {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: How to specify that when hover the mouse over the row it does not remove the highlight. I have tried `.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-row:hover,
.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-footer-row:hover .hovered {
  background: none;
}` but still when I hover the mouse over the row it removed the selection highlight colour.

Comment: If you want to have the same color as the one from the `.highlighted` class wether it's highlighted or hovered then I would suggest to not use anymore the `.hovered` class and to use instead a CSS variable like this :
```css
:host {
  --bg-color: green;
}

.highlighted {
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-row:hover,
.mat-mdc-table .mat-mdc-footer-row:hover {
  background: var(--bg-color);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are very good at that. Would you mind please to comment on what you have just suggested. It works beautifully. What is this host with  --bg-color and the var(--bg-color). I have never seen that before?

Comment: 1. `:host` is a **pseudo class selector**, in short it allows you to style your `app` component without affecting the other components (see: https://cutt.ly/RwllivhD for more details). It's not mandatory to use this pseudo class to achieve what you want to do here but it was more convenient for me.  
2. `--bg-color` is a custom property or a variable if you prefer (you cna change it's name with whatever you like). To use this custom property you have to use the `var()` function (see: https://cutt.ly/xwllu5db). To be noticed: this is not something inherited from Angular, it's a CSS concept.

Answer (score 2):

Using custom styles with angular material components can be really hard sometimes.

Try using this in your ***.component.ts***:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'yourSelector',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And then, in your SCSS (or CSS) styles file, you can add this BEFORE any selector and will probably work:

```
:host::ng-deep .mat-list-text {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: While it's easier to apply the problem with this solution is that Angular deprecated the `ng-deep` selector: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep